# How to evaluate AB test for determining price elasticity?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, ab-test

Given a standard AB test setup on an e-commerce platform with users randomly seeing same product priced either with control price or a variant, how does one correctly assess the results?

Say, after a week we have X sales for control and Y sales for variant. We are not looking at conversion rates, all we are interested in is the sales uplift from one discount point to another. How do we know if the difference that we observe is statistically significant (Chi squared goodness of fit?) and that the total sales are enough to trust the observed uplift with a given confidence level?

Comment: if I understand you want a statistical test that the total sales (money) Y > total sales X?. So I think you need some average that you can compare. eg you could look at the average sales per day (or hour or..)  and do a paired t-test? if your average sales is significantly different then your total sales is also.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I was considering comparing average sales across products, but there in general one can expect very low numbers so that didn't feel like a proper way to go. Average per hour sounds interesting, how would one evaluate if we have enough samples then?

Comment: look at test power callculators eg https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/gpower/power-analysis-for-paired-sample-t-test/

Comment: Thanks! Also, if I am actually interested in number of articles sold instead of money, would this change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is a generic and simple method for your question.

assume your raw data like this:

- randomization unit is user_id: each user have a consistent treatment and may have multiple visits/transactions, ending with a purchase or not
- y can be purchase amount or is purchased(0/1)

```
library(boot)
library(tidyverse)

df_raw <- tibble(
  user_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6),
  treat   = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
  y       = c(0, 100, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0)
)

# experiment users
df_user <- distinct(df_raw, user_id)

    # A tibble: 10 × 3
       user_id treat     y
         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
     1       1     0     0
     2       1     0   100
     3       1     0     0
     4       2     1    30
     5       3     0     0
     6       3     0     0
     7       4     0     0
     8       5     1    10
     9       5     1     0
    10       6     0     0
```

```
# This is a little different from the standard bootstrap t-test, which fixes the A/B group sample size, but more like a case resample bootstrap regression
get_stat <- function(df_user, inds, df_raw) {
  df_raw %>%
    # we resample user not transaction, for the randomization unit is user
    inner_join(df_user[inds, ], by = 'user_id') %>%
    summarise(
      # transaction level
      transaction_cnt_0 = sum(if_else(treat == 0, 1, 0)),
      transaction_cnt_1 = sum(if_else(treat == 1, 1, 0)),

      # user level
      user_cnt_0 = n_distinct(if_else(treat == 0, user_id, NA_real_)),
      user_cnt_1 = n_distinct(if_else(treat == 1, user_id, NA_real_)),

      y0 = sum(if_else(treat == 0, y, 0)),
      y1 = sum(if_else(treat == 1, y, 0)),

      # y0 = max(if_else(treat == 0, y, 0)),
      # y1 = max(if_else(treat == 1, y, 0)),

      # average sales per user
      diff_user = y1 / user_cnt_1 - y0 / user_cnt_0,

      # average sales per transaction
      diff_transaction = y1 / transaction_cnt_1 - y0 / transaction_cnt_0
    ) %>%

    pull(diff_user)

}

boot_res <- boot(df_user, get_stat, R = 1000, df_raw = df_raw)
boot_res

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = df_user, statistic = get_stat, R = 1000, df_raw = df_raw)


Bootstrap Statistics :
    original  bias    std. error
t1* -6.66667  -4.785     32.3452
```

````
# if you hava a large sample, this may hava compute problems
# boot.ci(boot_res, type = 'bca')

boot.ci(boot_res, type = 'basic')
```
````